# Reusing lia tactic to prove decidability

Tags: coq

I have an abstract syntax for Presburger arithmetic, along with a fixpoint function determining a given formula's propositional denotation (you can see it here: https://gist.github.com/d4hines/d9a0c674f324cab46d2cf0967bde1ac3).

I'd like to prove that the truth value of any given formula is decidable. Since it's Presburger arithmetic, I know it must decidable. I've heard that the decision procedures for Presburger arithmetic are very complicated. I'd like to reuse the [existing one in Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/micromega.html#coq:tacn.lia).

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can, outside of looking at its code to implement your own version.

Comment: I got `Error: The reference lia was not found in the current environment.` -- how does one fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few reasons why `lia` will not be of great help to you.

1. A small true goal like `exists x : Z, 2 < x < 4` is not solved by lia: this tactic is not complete for Prestburger arithmetic
2. Even if `lia` was complete for Presburger, it would act as an oracle: giving you an answer every time you need one for a true formula.  But when presented with a false formula, `lia` only says to Coq **I can't do it**, it does not say *I have a proof that this can't be done*.  In other words, the information that a proof procedure is complete may not be stored in the Coq system as a *Coq readable proof*.

Comment: So does this mean that HNTW is correct in his/her comment that the only way to achieve a proof that my logic is decidable is to reimplement a Presburger decision procedure?

Comment: Yes, I agree with HNTW.